# Mac requirement for Delphi XE4 Professional + Mobile Add-On

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe4

I can't find information on what are the system requirements for Mac for the mobile add-on for Delphi XE4 (Professional).

My understanding is that XCode is still required to sign the app binary and to deploy it on a test device and/or App Store.

Our Mac is so old that the minimum requirement of OSX for the latest XCode won't even install.

I'd like to know if we need to have the Mac upgraded to accomodate this.

Comment: Any Mac that can run OS X Mountain Lion should do okay. I have been using an iMac from 2007 to run XCode and have had no problems using it or the PAServer (the way you connect to the Delphi IDE) with XE3. I don't expect XE4 will have changed that. So I'd say, Core2Duo or better, if you value the finite hours of life you have left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - found the answer: https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/rad-studio-data-sheet.pdf second page:

> PC running Windows connected  with an Intel-based Mac, with 2  GB RAM
>   or more, running OS X 
>   10.8 (Mountain Lion) or 10.7 (Lion)  over a local area network using a  SSH, VNC or Windows file sharing solution

Apologies & much appreciated if you've attempted to help me:

Answer (score 2):

XCode will still be required, so of course your Mac system will have to be updated to be able to support it.

The [documentation for XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Mac_OS_X_Application_Development) will give you the minimums requirements for that version, and you should require XE4 to at least require those minimum requirements. As it doesn't seem your existing system meets those, you can probably be sure it won't support the requirements for XE4.

You can also contact Embarcadero Sales with pre-sales question, with the email address you'd expect (Sales at the companyname.com).